# Using ERB with Handlebars templates

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, handlebars.js

I have a modal that makes new tags with ajax. It does a POST method with the Tags parameters without recharging the view. So I want, depending on the "price_type" parameter chosen, to render one price div or another. Im using Handlebars so I suppose this is not ruby's  conditional responsability (because of AJAX), but Handlebars conditionals responsability.

The problem is I tried plenty of ways of making Handlebars conditionals with no success.

I want to achieve the equivalent of this with Handlebars conditionals, where `@tag.price_type` is stored as `{{price_type}}` in JS. Since I'm using AJAX, if I try this it wont work.

```
    <script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
      <% if @tag.price_type === 1 %>
        <span class="small right white article_price">{{min_price}} €</span>
      <% elsif @tag.price_type === 2 %>
        <span class="small right white article_price">{{min_price}} €</span> - <span class="small right white article_price">{{max_price}} €</span>
      <% else %>
        <span class="small right white article_price">No sabe</span>
      <% end %>
    </script>
```

Is it possible? Maybe saving the file as hbs.erb? 
If not, how would the pure Handlebars template be? I tried making a custom Helper which I didn't understand, but nothing. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to name your file something with `.hbs.erb` at the end of it, rather than simply `.hbs` .

This will encourage Rails to compile the file first as an `.erb` file (injecting `erb` data into the `.hbs` file), then Rails will render the file as a `.hbs` (Rails compiles files in the order of file extensions from right to left).

Comment: I renamed the file to .hbs.erb, but it always goes to the "ELSE", and the first 2 conditionals won't work. I know the params (price_type) are being stored into the ddbb correctly. Where can the error be?

Comment: @Gibson You simply have a logic issue somewhere unrelated to the original question of this post. Are you intending to use the ruby version of the `===` operator and not the javascript version?  When Rails reads the erb tags it will compute whatever is inside of them as if it were Ruby, not javascript.  You might mean to change those to simply `==`.

Comment: You are right. The problem is with the logic. I'm really stuck with this. I tried with 2 == instead and didn't work. I suppose I will need to make Handlebars conditionals, but I don't know how. I have the value of @tag.price_type stored in {{price_type}}, but i don't know how to make a conditional with if {{price_type}} == 1, show me this, but if {{price_type}} == 2, show me that. Else, show "Nothing". I tried it before but nothing.

Comment: The answer for the original question is valid, you should mark it as correct and create a new post specifically about your comment so you can get more help.  I would troubleshoot with you but I'm about to leave my office and don't have time.  It is unlikely someone else will read deep into the comments to help you though, so you should create a new topic/question (it is appropriate to create a new topic once the initial question was answered anyway).